# How to strip out leading time stamp?

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching, member-enumeration

I have some log files.
Some of the UPDATE SQL statements are getting errors, but not all.
I need to know all the statements that are getting errors so I can find the pattern of failure.

I can sort all the log files and get the unique lines, like this:

```
$In = "C:\temp\data"
$Out1 = "C:\temp\output1"
$Out2 = "C:\temp\output2"

Remove-Item $Out1\*.*
Remove-Item $Out2\*.*

# Get the log files from the last 90 days
Get-ChildItem $In -Filter *.log | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)} |
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    #filter and save content to a file
    $content | Where-Object {$_ -match 'STATEMENT'} | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content $Out1\$_
}

# merge all the files, sort unique, write to output
Get-Content $Out2\* | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content $Out3\output.txt
```

Works great.

But some of the logs have a leading date-time stamp in the leading 24 char. I need to strip that out, or *all* those lines are unique.

If it helps, all the files either have the leading timestamp or they don't. The lines are not mixed within a single file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# Get the log files from the last 90 days
Get-ChildItem $In -Filter *.log | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)} |
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    #filter and save content to a file
    $s = $content | Where-Object {$_ -match 'STATEMENT'} 
    # strip datetime from front if exists
    If (Where-Object {$s.Substring(0,1) -Match '/d'}) { $s = $s.Substring(24) }
    $s | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content $Out1\$_
}

# merge all the files, sort unique, write to output
Get-Content $Out1\* | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content $Out2\output.txt
```

But it just write the lines out without stripping the leading chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `/d` should be `\d` (`\` is the escape character in general, and character-class shortcuts such as `d` for a digit<sup>[1]</sup>  must be prefixed with it).
- Use a single pipeline that passes the `Where-Object` output to a `ForEach-Object` call where you can perform the conditional removal of the numeric prefix.

```bash
$content | 
  Where-Object { $_ -match 'STATEMENT' } |
  ForEach-Object { if ($_[0] -match '\d') { $_.Substring(24) } else { $_ } } |
  Set-Content $Out1\$_
```

---

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, `\d` matches *everything* that the Unicode standard considers a  digit, not just the ASCII-range digits `0` to `9`; to limit matching to the latter, use `[0-9]`.</sup>